# Friendly URL's with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I want to get friendly URL in Ember.js but, for now, it's only works with the ID.

How can I use /#/post/sample-title ?

Maybe this can be easier (and valid for me): /#/12/sample-title (12 is the ID).

router.js

```
this.resource('post', { path: '/post/:post_slug/' });
```

post_route.js

```
(...)
return App.Post.find(model.post_slug);
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

To get a different property of your model to be used as the dynamic segment in your URL you need to use the `serialize` hook of your route:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serialize: function(model) {
    return {
      post_slug: model.get('post_slug')
    };
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's works! But when I type the direct url don't appears nothing! Just works from a click of a link in the template.

Comment: @DanPalmerio, do you have a `model` hook still setup in your `PostRoute`?

Answer (score 0):

For Ember 3

```js
export default class PostRoute extends Route {
  serialize(section) { 
    return { post_slug: section.get('post_slug') }; 
  }
}
```